# collection traversal order with mongoose methods like findOne() or findOneAndRemove()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How do mongoose methods like findOne() or findOneAndRemove()  traverse a collection ? which object will this kind of methods return ? the oldest entry ? the first object from left to right in the collection ? do these methods sort collections by object id in ascending order during their execution ? or will it return a random object falling under the specified condition ? the Mongoose API Documentation just says "finds one document", it's probably obvious but it is not to me, hence this question ;)

[EDIT]

findOneAndRemove() documentation >>> 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove
simply states ("Finds a matching document")
       findOne() documentation >>>
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne
(simply states "Finds one document")

How can I be sure which document will be found by these methods if I have, lets say, two books in a books collection that have the same value under a "name" property ?

This question occured to me while running tests using mocha during my learning of MongoDB >>>
https://github.com/yactouat/JSNotions/blob/master/learningMongoDBMongoose/test/delete_test.js

Comment: Please show us what you have found so far. Link or anything is appreciated. We are not here to do the work for you. Show us some progress and we will help lead the way

Comment: of course not, I am not expecting that anyone "does the work for me"; I am just trying to understand how these methods work ;)

Comment: just edited the question, sorry I cant be more clearer but I didnt find a specific answer to that subject in the questions base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most driver functions correspond to Mongo DB's methods.
If you Google it a bit, you can find all Mongo shell's functions and their documentation.

For example, according to: [findOne documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/index.html) on Mongo DB's site:

> Returns one document that satisfies the specified query criteria on
>   the collection or view. **If multiple documents satisfy the query, this
>   method returns the first document according to the natural order which
>   reflects the order of documents on the disk**. In capped collections,
>   natural order is the same as insertion order. If no document satisfies
>   the query, the method returns null.

Comment: ok thanks, my mistake, went on mongoose API doc instead of mongoDB's

Comment: No worries, and don't feel bad, we are all here to learn ;)
if this answer solved your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: thanks ! I'm discovering MongoDB and was a bit confused about capped collections because of the very existence of methods like remove() for instance, but it all became much clearer, thanks to your link that reminded me of this simple word : FIFO

Comment: With pleasure..
Most of what I know about MongoDB I learned from their docs. They have very good ones..